# Mysterious "Ingestion" Serverless error in AWS Lambda logs

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-kinesis

I'm encountering a weird error when one of my Lambda functions is invoked. I have never seen this error. Google searches haven't helped at all. Here's what it looks like :

```
Ingestion server error 
{
    "request": {
        "url": "https://core.serverless.com/ingestion/kinesis/v1/request-response",
        "headers": {
            "accept-encoding": "gzip",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "serverless_token": "[redacted]"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 500,
        "text": "{\"message\":\"Something went wrong forwarding RequestResponseEvent data.\"}"
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with my code since my function works. Occasionally though, for periods of up to about an hour, my function fails with this error. Looking at the error it seems that the Serverless Framework is trying to redirect some data to their servers, for some reason, and failing in the process.

Why is this happening? What is Serverless trying to achieve? What can I do to stop this error from happening? I'm desperate for any insight.

I've also stumbled upon some environment variables that Serverless seems to be setting automatically :

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER | /opt/otel-extension/internal/exec-wrapper.sh |
| OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES | sls_service_name=ODAC-API,sls_stage=dev,sls_org_id=[redacted] |
| SLS_OTEL_REPORT_LOGS_URL | https://core.serverless.com/ingestion/kinesis/v1/logs |
| SLS_OTEL_REPORT_METRICS_URL | https://core.serverless.com/ingestion/kinesis/v1/metrics |
| SLS_OTEL_REPORT_REQUEST_HEADERS | serverless_token=[redacted] |
| SLS_OTEL_REPORT_REQUEST_RESPONSE_URL | https://core.serverless.com/ingestion/kinesis/v1/request-response |
| SLS_OTEL_REPORT_TRACES_URL | https://core.serverless.com/ingestion/kinesis/v1/traces |
| SLS_OTEL_USER_SETTINGS | {} |

I have no idea what these are for but it seems related (same url).

Could it have something to do with the `sls --console` command that I ran? Has it setup some mechanisms to monitor my functions? If so, how can I undo this?

This is really bugging me. Google seems to know nothing of this error, whatever I try to search. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a backend error coming from the Serverless.com's API.

My guess is you can set `console: false` in your `serverless.yml` file and then re-deploy your service to remove the instrumentation - but I haven't confirmed that, it seems absent from their [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/console/docs)

Comment: This really makes me want to avoid using their console service... Hopefully, this fixes the issue. The thing is, the error only happened after hours of continus invocations so reproducing the error is quite hard. Will report back if the problem persists.